# mod_rewrite not finding files that exists

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am working on a project that uses Apache 2.2 and we are implementing a rewrite rule that uses the file on the local disk if it exists and if it doesn't then it using another server to server the file.  To simplify the problem I have just put a rule in that redirects to a given URL if the file doesn't exist:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) /notfound.html
```

Now the output on that request from the rewrite log is as follows:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/May/2016:16:54:01 +1000] [www.blah.com/sid#7f8a4ee0f358][rid#7f8a4f45d7d8/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /index.html
127.0.0.1 - - [30/May/2016:16:54:01 +1000] [www.blah.com/sid#7f8a4ee0f358][rid#7f8a4f45d7d8/initial] (3) applying pattern '^(.*)' to uri '/index.html'
127.0.0.1 - - [30/May/2016:16:54:01 +1000] [www.blah.com/sid#7f8a4ee0f358][rid#7f8a4f45d7d8/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='/index.html' pattern='!-f' => matched
127.0.0.1 - - [30/May/2016:16:54:01 +1000] [www.blah.com/sid#7f8a4ee0f358][rid#7f8a4f45d7d8/initial] (2) rewrite '/index.html' -> '/notfound.html'
127.0.0.1 - - [30/May/2016:16:54:01 +1000] [www.blah.com/sid#7f8a4ee0f358][rid#7f8a4f45d7d8/initial] (2) local path result: /notfound.html
127.0.0.1 - - [30/May/2016:16:54:01 +1000] [www.blah.com/sid#7f8a4ee0f358][rid#7f8a4f45d7d8/initial] (2) prefixed with document_root to /var/www/html/notfound.html
127.0.0.1 - - [30/May/2016:16:54:01 +1000] [www.blah.com/sid#7f8a4ee0f358][rid#7f8a4f45d7d8/initial] (1) go-ahead with /var/www/html/notfound.html [OK]
```

When I turn off the rewrite rules and run the same command I get a 200 response from the server.

The server has permissions to view the file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` instead of `%{REQUEST_URI}`, thus:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) /notfound.html
```

`%{REQUEST_URI}` will contain only `/index.html`, so it won't work unless the filesystem has an `index.html` file in the root.

`%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` will contain the full path to the requested filename (including the Apache directory root for that domain)

Note that `REQUEST_URI` and `REQUEST_FILENAME` might happen to be equal under some specific circumstances, but more often than not, they won't. So if you are checking for a filename in the server's local filesystem (as it's the case), use the specific.

Comment: Strangely this hasn't worked either.  I suspect it might be some configuration issue in the server but I need to find it.

Comment: Strange indeed. Can you post your complete `.htaccess` ?

Comment: We manage to sorted it out, the underlying HTTP call was giving a periodic 403 due to a permissions issue.  Your fix was the correct one so I will mark it as such, thank you.